# IE 11 has null recordset when using UseHeader=true

Tags: javascript, activex, internet-explorer-11

I create recordset from tab-separated file using the OBJECT tag. In IE<11 it works good, but in IE11 parameter "UseHeader" with value "true" does not work correctly.
If it is set to "false", recordset is loaded well, but if I set it to "true" only first row (with names) is loaded, and recordset has 0 rows. I use IE5 compatibility mode, but it does not help. Code is below

```html
<OBJECT classid=CLSID:333C7BC4-460F-11D0-BC04-0080C7055A83 height=0 id="data2" width=0>
<PARAM NAME="RowDelim" VALUE="&#10;">
<PARAM NAME="FieldDelim" VALUE="&#9;">
<PARAM NAME="TextQualifier" VALUE='"'>
<PARAM NAME="EscapeChar" VALUE="">
<PARAM NAME="UseHeader" VALUE="-1">
<PARAM NAME="SortColumn" VALUE="SORTBA">
<PARAM NAME="Filter" VALUE="BRN=zx">
<PARAM NAME="DataURL" VALUE="text/brand_history.txt">
</OBJECT>
```